# How to split enum into multiple categories in Java

Tags: java, enums

I have different groups of reasons based on which decisions are made. I have basically 3 categories, `Approved Group`, `Suppressed Group` and `Rejection Group`. My `Rejection Group` is split into two - `Block` and `Action`. What would be the best way to model this?

I will be storing the type of a Decision in a class.

```
public class A{
    //some Members
    DecisionGroup decision
}
```

I will be getting a `List<ClassA>` and will be requiring to split this into 4 lists, one each for the different type. I was thinking of going with an enum, but I am not sure how do I split Rejection Group in two.

Comment: "My Rejection Group is split into two block and Action" - didn`t understand. Perhaps you shoud show your enum and groups. 
About enum groups, i ordinary use constant java.util.EnumSet with enum values in this group, and check with contains method.

Comment: @ZufarMuhamadeev By split into two, I mean that it contains two types: Block and Action. Rest of the groups have no types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
enum Category {
    Approved, Suppressed, Rejected;

enum Group {
    ApprovedGroup(Category.Approved),
    SuppressedGroup(Category.Suppressed),
    BlockRejectedGroup(Category.Rejected),
    ActionRejectedGroup(Category.Rejected);

    Group( Category category ){...}

    Category getCategory(){...}
}
```

enums can have attributes, so you might define the 4 groups and give them the "major" category as a parameter which defines the List.

Or you can even make the List itself a property of the enum Group.

Alternatively, write an enum Category that contains methods to determine the Group which defines the list.

```
enum Category {
   Approved  {
      @Override 
      public Group select(A a) {
           return Group.ApprovedGroup;
      }
   },
   Suppressed  {
      @Override 
      public Group select(A a) {
           return Group.SuppressedGroup;
      }
   },
   Rejected  {
      @Override 
      public Group select(A a) {
           ...
           return Group.BlockRejectedGroup;
           ...
           return Group.ActionRejectedGroup;
      }
   };

   public abstract Group select(A a);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems a better way to approach this. Also how would I go about splitting the list of ClassA based on block or action rejection group?

Comment: @user1692342 What are the values of DecisionGroup? Can they the same as my `enum Group`?

Comment: @luane Shouldn't the classA contain the Category rather than group?

Comment: I'm a bit confused now - four lists or three lists, and how do you distinguish Block and Action?

Comment: I will need to extract 4 lists. I was thinking of keeping Category in classA, but I guess it makes sense to directly put the group.

Comment: OK. You can have individual methods in an enum of three Categories to determine the Group for the List based on additional properties of class A.

Comment: @user1692342 Added a variant that lets you combine the List selection logic with a set of three Categories.

Answer (score 2):

If your structure is more complicated than an enum, think about writing your own class. Don't forget to overwrite equals/hashcode to make sure that two same decisions are "equal".

Comment: I think enum is good enough since it is just bunch of constant strings